# Reading an Attribute from a XML/RSS file using AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

very simple question, i have this: (only a part of the complete rss file)

```
 <item>
      <title>Ok, de regalo de San Valentin me pueden dar un viaje a Playa del Carmen! Digo, entre todos lo pagan! No?? #So&#241;arNoCuestaNada</title>
      <link>http://twitter.com/glenyvalente/statuses/37202068301295616</link>
      <description>Ok, de regalo de San Valentin me pueden dar un viaje a &lt;b&gt;Playa&lt;/b&gt; del Carmen! Digo, entre todos lo pagan! No?? &lt;a href=&quot;http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23So%C3%B1arNoCuestaNada&quot; onclick=&quot;pageTracker._setCustomVar(2, 'result_type', 'recent', 3);pageTracker._trackPageview('/intra/hashtag/#So&#241;arNoCuestaNada');&quot;&gt;#So&#241;arNoCuestaNada&lt;/a&gt;</description>
      <pubDate>Mon, 14 Feb 2011 17:30:38 +0000</pubDate>
      <guid>http://twitter.com/glenyvalente/statuses/37202068301295616</guid>
      <author>glenyvalente@twitter.com (Gleny Valente)</author>
      <media:content type="image/jpg" width="48" url="http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1225905511/S5030401_normal.JPG" height="48"/>
      <google:image_link>http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1225905511/S5030401_normal.JPG</google:image_link>
      <google:location>Venezuela</google:location>
      <twitter:metadata>
        <twitter:result_type>recent</twitter:result_type>
      </twitter:metadata>
    </item>
```

And i read `<title>` and `<pubDate>` using:

```
function rssLoaded(evt:Event):void {
    rssXML = XML(rssLoader.data);
    for(var item:String in rssXML.channel.item) {
    fechas.push(rssXML.channel.item[item].pubDate.substr(0, 16));
    titulos.push(rssXML.channel.item[item].title);
    trace(rssXML.channel.item[item].media:content.attributes.url);
    total=total+1;
    }
    trace(total);
}
```

but, `trace(rssXML.channel.item[item].media:content.attributes.url);` is always empty, so how can i read the attribute **url** from the tag `<media>` ??? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok so try this

try rssXML.channel.item[item].namespace("media")::content.@url

Comment: no, Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 19 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before colon.

Comment: no again: Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 19 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before doublecolon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the information that will get you the closest answer to your request:
In your AS code section add this import:

```
private var media:Namespace = new Namespace("http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");
```

Then in your function block(s) you can access the media namespace in this way:

```
var urlString:String = rssXML.media::content.@url[0];
```

media::content uses the media namespace, which is imported above.  Now you can access the members like content.  Within that is the member url, which can be an indexed array -- so we specifically say @url[0] to obtain the first entry.

If in doubt, you can consult this additional answer:
[XML AS3 Selecting Image URL Namespace value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454300/xml-as3-selecting-image-url-namespace-value/16465472#16465472)