# XML AS3 Selecting Image URL Namespace value

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

Basically, for a project I am making a comic reader in flash with XML provided by a [comic strip on deviantart](http://backend.deviantart.com/rss.xml?q=gallery%3apitiyindee/35272208&type=deviation). I'm only so far trying to figure out how to extract the url of an image within an item object, I think I'm mostly struggling with learning how the syntax is supposed to be. I've tried: `var imgUrl:String = comicXML.children().content.@url;` with comicXML being the url request. Tracing comicXML alone Does work correctly and gives back the XML.

Maybe someone can give me a hint or two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one, partly because the hangup isn't so much basic XML processing as it is dealing with namespaces. You'll notice within your `<item>`, there is a tag `<media:content url="blahblahblah" />`

That "`media:`" makes `content` part of the media namespace, and it allows us to have two tags with the same name be part of a parent tag without conflicting with tags of the same name in other namespaces. You can see that `<item>` has both a `<title>` and a `<media:title>` and doesn't complain about it.

You'll also notice, in your root tag, there are several namespaces (media, atom, and creativeCommons) defined with xmlns:

```
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
     xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
     xmlns:creativeCommons="http://backend.userland.com/creativeCommonsRssModule"
     version="2.0">
```

To use them, you'll need to create a Namespace variable:

```
var myXML:XML = new XML( loader.data );
var media:Namespace = myXML.namespace("media");
```

Now that we've created media, which represents the xmlns:media, we can access any of the tags with the media: prefix with code like this (notice the :: double-colon):

```
trace(myXML.channel.item[0].media::content.@url);
```

---

I found these links to be helpful (especially the second one!):

http://lab.revoke.ca/2009/05/as3-xml-namespace/

http://coursesweb.net/actionscript/xml-e4x-namespaces

Answer (score 0):

First you must load the url request and then cast the data into a xml

```
var myLoad:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoad.load(new URLRequest("art.xml"));
myLoad.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getXML);
var myXML:XML;

function getXML(e:Event):void {
  myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
}
```

Then from there you want to use an XMLList to retrieve information you want:

example xml:

```
<pictures>
<item>
   <file>filename.jpg</file>
</item>
<item>
   <file>filename2.jpg</file>
</item>
</pictures>
```

so Then to use XMLList be as followed:

```
var xl:XMLList = myXML.item;
var i:int = 0;
for each (var labelElement:XML in xl) 
{
   trace(labelElement.data.text()[i]);
   ++i;
}
```

Hope this helps.